# Где и как прописать library path для Bower?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm, library, bower

собираю свой ***gulp*** хочу упростить подключение ***frameworks*** как в css так и в js то-есть

**libs.sass**

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot'
```

**libs.coffee**

```
require 'jquery/dist/jquery.js'
```

и по умолчанию все так и работает ,
но я пользуюсь bower для установки ***frameworks***
а он все устанавливает в папку *bower_components* .

и теперь так не работает а работает только так

**libs.sass**

```
@import '../bower_components/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot'
```

**libs.coffee**

```
require '../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
```

и в случае с css у меня получилось это сделать прописав параметры

**gulpfile.js**

```
    //  Compile sass into CSS
    gulp.task( 'css:libs' ,( ) => {

        return gulp.src( conf.path.src.sassLibs )

            //////////////////////////////
            .pipe( sass( { includePaths: ['./bower_components'] } )
            //////////////////////////////

            .pipe( gulp.dest( conf.path.build.css ) )

    } );



    //  Compile coffee into JS
    gulp.task( 'js:libs' ,( ) => {

        return gulp.src( conf.path.src.coffeeLibs )

            .pipe( plumber() )
            .pipe( coffee( { bare: true } ) )
            .pipe( browserify() )
            .pipe( babel( conf.opion.presets ) )
            .pipe( prettify() )
            .pipe( gulp.dest( conf.path.build.js ) )
            .pipe( uglify() )
            .pipe( rename( conf.opion.rename ) )
            .pipe( gulp.dest( conf.path.build.js ) )

    //  End js libs task
    } );
```

Но в случае с js я не нашел решения ,

можно где то прописать этот - ***( library ,resource root )*** *path*

через **package.json** или **.noderc** ?

Не затрагивая при этом переменные операционки , что бы решение было кросс-платформенное !

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос gulp задачу для компиляции js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    /**
 * Compile SCSS to CSS, and minify.
 */
gulp.task('sass', function ( ){
    gulp.src(source + '/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({compatibility: 'ie9'}))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});


/**
 * Компиляция Vendor библиотек и файлов JS , Concat and minify.
 */
gulp.task('js-vendor', function () {
    gulp.src(source + '/vendor/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(plumber(plumberErrorHandler))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(concat('vendor.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(destination + '/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

если я тебя правильно понял, то твоя сложность где урл вписать.
начем с того, что это не сложно 
тебе нужно всегда 2 переменные

```
// Config of folder structure.
var source = './src';
var destination = './app/dist';
```

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://github.com/tbunitrade/website/blob/master/gulpfile.js) данная ссылка это мой сборщик. как видишь у отдельно собираю библиотеки джаваскрипта и отдельно компилирую кастомные стили.

return gulp.src( conf.path.+ src +.coffeeLibs )

По сути тебе нужно **src** самому указать в таске JS js:libs

Answer (score 0):

*я сделал так* ,
вот пути

```
library:
    css: 
        includePaths: ./libs
    js:  
        paths: 
            - ./libs
```

**js**

```
.pipe( browserify( conf.library.js ) )
```

**css**

```
.pipe( sass( conf.library.css )
```